# How to get all cookies starting with a word using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can I get an array containing names of all cookies starting with `word`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Entirely functional approach:

```
document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(c) {
    return c.trim().indexOf('word') === 0;
}).map(function(c) {
    return c.trim();
});
```

With explanation:

```
//Get a list of all cookies as a semicolon+space-separated string
document.cookie.split(';')
//Filter determines if an element should remain in the array.  Here we check if a search string appears at the beginning of the string
.filter(function(c) {
    return c.trim().indexOf('word') === 0;
})
//Map applies a modifier to all elements in an array, here we trim spaces on both sides of the string
.map(function(c) {
    return c.trim();
});
```

ES6:

```
document.cookie.split(';')
    .filter(c => c.startsWith('word'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
            return "";
        }
```

You should then be able to use getCookie(name) and it should return a string containing the cookies. Then just use split on the returned value to get the array.
Hope this works for you.